# How to connect Rails and devise backend with a android application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am implementing an Android App to login with a web application developed in Rails where Devise is used for authentication. I do not know how to connect to devise form my application because the option "token_authenticable" is deprecated. What the best solution? There are some extensions of devise to connect from a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

you can use token authentication rather than simple Devise, add following gem in gemfile

```
# Use device for authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_token_authentication'
```

follow documention [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication)

Comment: From the examples I have seen, I understand the following: the user pass by GET or POST request the email and auth token, and if this parameters are corrected, the authentication was successfull. But my user enters the first time with email and password. After how do you get the token for subsequent requests?One solution is to send the token as a response to authentication, but would make it vulnerable to attacks of the "man in the middle".Are there other solutions taken to make the token secure?